# Core Data: Fetch and group different entities based on date created

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data

**Case:**
I am working on an app using Core Data with 2 different entities `Note` and `Sleep`. During a day there may be added instances of these entities multiple times.

Note stores `timestamp` (Date), a `note` (String) and a few other irrelevant attributes. Used to take daily notes. 
Sleep stores `timeStart` (Date) and `timeEnd` (Date) - Used to track the user's sleep.

**Issue**
I want to fetch all the entries of both Entities `Note` + `Sleep` and group them by  `timestamp`and `timeEnd`; so it can be displayed in a table view with a cell/row for each date.

The sleep data will be used to calculate the total hours of sleep (e.g. if the user sleeps twice a day)

Some days there might be only Notes and other days only Sleep.

How would I go about this? I hope it makes sense; otherwise please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to group them by DAY rather than Date, bearing in mind that Core Data Date will be down to seconds of perhaps even milliseconds and so you may have some difficulty matching Note and Sleep records.  It might be easier to create a relationship between Note and Sleep(s) where there is one Note per DAY and none-or-more Sleeps per DAY.  Then Note can have a transient attribute that calculates the hours of sleep from the related Sleep records

Comment: Thanks for your input Duncan; I can see I might have to rethink the way I structure my app. I will need some time to figure out how I want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A Core Data fetch request can only fetch objects of one particular entity (and optionally
the sub-entities). The same is true for a fetched results controller.

Therefore to display
`Note` and `Sleep` entities together in a table view, you have the following options:

- use a single entity that holds all attributes, or
- make `Note` and `Sleep` inherit from a common parent entity, or
- create a third entity `Entry` with the `timestamp` attribute and to-one relationships to `Note` and `Sleep`.

Note that in the second case Core Data would also store all objects in a single 
table containing all attributes.

In either case, you can sort the objects on the timestamp, or group them
into sections using the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter of the fetched results
controller.

The only alternative would be to fetch the objects separately and merge them, but then
you lose all advantages of the fetched results controller, like automatic
change tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Martin, I will give the third method a try and get back to you soon (and hopefully mark your suggestion as the answer)